# Create iptables rules

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, fedora-13

I want to make the following rules in `iptables`:

1. Open port `80`, `5432` and `22` to all IP addresses
2. Open port `27017` only to these IP addresses `x.x.x.0/24`

In all the cases I want both tcp and udp access.

Can you please tell what the config should be in `iptables` for this setup to work?

Comment: "open port" is not really technically correct. Sometimes it does matter which part (you or the remote host) initiates a connection. This will result in different firewall rules.

Answer (score 1):

Do a quick Google search for an iptables tutorial. On a Fedora system, your firewall rules are kept in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`. You might want rules that look similar to:

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p 5432 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p 27017 -s x.x.x.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Although, I would not recommend opening ports 22 and 5432 to the world. The SSH connections should be locked down to as few sources as possible, and even then you might want to consider additional restrictions. The database connections should be restricted to the web server and those machines that you use to manage the database.